# Need some help coding zen cart product layout

Tags: php, html, product, zen-cart

I am currently working on my ecommerce website. Having a lot of trouble and I do not know where can I start editing the positioning of the product lay out.

For example:

```
http://www.picaflor-azul.com/free-demos/index.php?main_page=product_info&cPath=1_4&products_id=2
```

Currently my product layout in page is like this.

What I would like to achieve is something like that:

```
https://jawbone.com/up
```

Something like the section of "Designed for everyday life"

I would like to place my product image on the right.

Currently because I have made the width of the page bigger, it was aligned on left. Is there any way I can do to make it center?

Is there any zen cart experts here to help? Because I do not know what file do I have to edit in order to achieve what I want..

Answer (score 0):

You will need to edit the product info display template file to get the layout you want. It can be found under the templates folder in your **custom** template folder.  tpl_product_info_display.php.

You can then style the elements on this page by modifying the main CSS stylesheet for your template.